# pygame not showing anything untill i close it

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote the following code:

```
import pygame

from pygame.locals import (
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    K_ESCAPE,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)

pygame.init()


SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))


running = True

while running:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
surf = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
surf.fill((0, 0, 0))
rect = surf.get_rect()

screen.blit(surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
pygame.display.flip()
```

But it only shows the code in the program for 2/3 frames after i close it i know this question was asked before but there was some issue in the loop but the loop is correct as far as i know what is wrong in this code?

Comment: Is your indendation like in your code? The whole code below screen.fill... is not part of the while loop and will only get executed after running is false.

Comment: No indendation is needed the part after 'running = false' doesn't go in the loop

Comment: Then where does the drawing happen more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python uses indentation to control scoping.  Your drawing code is outside the scope of your game loop.  If you indent all the drawing codes to be inside your game loop then that will draw it until you exit the loop.

Comment: Ohhh thank you stupid mistake i'm a rookie @noobius